# Flutter How to print selected value on textfield when keyboard is hide

Tags: flutter, dropbox

hellow thank you in advance can you help me....! i made dropbox under the textfield..and in that case...i dont want keyboard...! but when i selecte value from my items then that value is not printed on my textfield...! let me explain you as live...
if you are a existing custmor the value is shown on textfield and when you select value MALE  FEMALE is not going to change.....! if i remove the onTap() {} from my textfield its going to change...! what should i do now i stuck here since 2,3 days
look at my code

```
         @override
         Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         return Scaffold(
         body: (_isLoading) ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()) : 
         FutureBuilder<UserUpdate>(
         future: _futureProfileupdate,
         builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
      
          TextEditingController _textEditingControllerGender = TextEditingController(text: 
            snapshot.data.gender);
            var items = ["MALE" , "FEMALE"];

            return Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SingleChildScrollView(
                    reverse: true,
                    child: new Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                     
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10,left: 30,right: 30),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            height: 65,
                            child: TextFormField(
                              onTap: (){
                                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
                              },   // if i remove this iteam is going to print on tetxfiled
                              focusNode: FocusNode(canRequestFocus: false),
                              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                              controller: _textEditingControllerGender,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                        color: Color(0x3df58634)
                                    )
                                ),
                                labelText: "GENDER",
                                labelStyle: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                                    color: const Color(0xfff58634)),
                                hintText: "GENDER",
                                hintStyle: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                                    color: const Color(0xfff58634)),
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                        5.0),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      color: const Color(0x3df58634),
                                    )
                                ),
                                suffixIcon: PopupMenuButton<String>(
                                  icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                                  onSelected: (String value) {
                                    _textEditingControllerGender.text = value;
                                  },
                                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                                    return items
                                        .map<PopupMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                                      return new PopupMenuItem(
                                          child: new Text(value), value: value);
                                    }).toList();
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                              onSaved: (String value) {
                                _Gender = value;
                              },

                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                       
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0,left: 230,right: 30),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: 140,
                            height: 45,
                            child: RaisedButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                  return;
                                }
                                setState(() {
                                  _isLoading = true;
                                });
                                Profile(
                                
                                  _textEditingControllerGender.text,
                                  
                                );
                              },
```

here is my json data....
plz help me i am stuck here since 2,3 days
UserUpdate userUpdateFromJson(String str) =>
UserUpdate.fromJson(json.decode(str));

```
String userUpdateToJson(UserUpdate data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class UserUpdate {
UserUpdate({
this.successCode,
this.successMessage,
this.firstName,
this.lastName,
this.email,
this.gender,  //i want thiis default to my textfiled and change when i select new
this.birthDate,
this.birthMonth,
this.anniversaryDate,
this.profilePicture,
});

String successCode;
String successMessage;
String firstName;
String lastName;
String email;
dynamic gender;
String birthDate;
String birthMonth;
String anniversaryDate;
String profilePicture;

factory UserUpdate.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserUpdate(
successCode: json["SuccessCode"],
successMessage: json["SuccessMessage"],
firstName: json["FirstName"],
lastName: json["LastName"],
email: json["Email"],
gender: json["Gender"],
birthDate: json["BirthDate"],
birthMonth: json["BirthMonth"],
anniversaryDate: json["AnniversaryDate"],
profilePicture: json["ProfilePicture"],
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
"SuccessCode": successCode,
"SuccessMessage": successMessage,
"FirstName": firstName,
"LastName": lastName,
"Email": email,
"Gender": gender,
"BirthDate": birthDate,
"BirthMonth": birthMonth,
"AnniversaryDate": anniversaryDate,
"ProfilePicture": profilePicture,
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have declared the *TextEditingController* inside build method . So anytime state changes or stream is listened, a new TextEditingController would be initialised.

Try declaring it globally and initialise it in initState . Through this your state would be preserved and value would be stored in TextEditingController

Comment: but how should i set default value comes from api..! thats why i build TextEditingController inside method

Comment: Any option to show default value comes from api response in Textfields